# How to dispose open UserControl in event?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am working with winforms.

I have a function which disposes its `UserControl`.

I used to call that when I clicked on a label and it worked fine(still does).
Now a added a devexpress control which as before on click disposes its own control. 
I call the same function as with the label but after the event is finished I get a null Pointer exeption where I create my Mainform (which isn´t disposed anywhere).

What am I missing here. I get that it is problematic to destroy the own usercontrol but why does that work when I click the label and not when I click the other user control? Can anyone give an explanation or a solution? Thanks!

```
private void DoDispose()
{
   this.Dispose();
}

private void breadCrumbEdit1_Properties_NodeClick(object sender, BreadCrumbNodeClickEventArgs e)
{
   DoDispose();
}

private void label1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   DoDispose();
}
```

Comment: Please give a sample of the code causing the issue, as otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: Remove all event handlers and usercontrol from winform and before disposing the usercontrol.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane did it.

Comment: 'this' is the Form object, you are disposing Form.

Comment: @SarveshMishra thats not it. I replaced this with a specific control and still have the same issue. + This would not explain why the same function works when I lick the label

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Dispose()` on `this`, which in this case would be the parent form.

Assuming that you're passing a `Control` object, change, your code like this;

```
public void DoDispose(object control)
{
    ((Control)object).Dispose();
}
```

Invoke as `DoDispose(sender)`

Now you're invoking `Dispose()` on the object that you're passing as the argument, rather that the parent form.

Comment: I changed it like you said but it doesn´t work. + does not explain why the function works when I click the label